# Why is Intellij IDEA highlighting text in standard out like a hyperlink?

Tags: intellij-idea, hyperlink

I am printing out the contents of a shapefile with ordinary printf statements and for some reason Intellij IDEA Ultimate is underlining and coloring blue a fragment of the output as though it thinks it is a hyperlink:

[image]

If I hover the mouse over the blue text, the cursor changes to a finger, like it is a hyperlink. Of course, nothing happens if I click it because it is obviously not a hyperlink. What is going on?

It seems to have something to do with the colons. If I delete them, then the text is no formatted. Also if I use only one colon like this:

```
X: -71.545101  Y 42.345041
```

Then there is also no formatting. Only if both colons are present does the blue underlining appear.

Answer (score 1):

`org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.execution.filters.GrCompilationErrorsFilterProvider` does that using the following pattern: `(file:)?(^|[\W])(?<file>(?:\p{Alpha}\:|/)[0-9 a-z_A-Z\-\\./]+): (?<line>[0-9]+).*`

Report a bug or disable Groovy plugin.